# How to detect huawei device models from other android models in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

As my application is cross platform, there is not any problem to encounter, but when it comes to android, some issues appear such that Huawei mobile devices don't have ability to access google play anymore, and they have their own application store (App Gallery), the problem comes as one of the specifications of my app is to **force users to download the latest version**, I don't know how to detect the Huawei devices to let users download my app from app gallery directly.

Answer (score 7):

You could follow this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/detection-of-hms-core-0000001081616060) detect the Huawei devices by checking whether a device has HMS Core APK installed.

```
// Create an HmsApiAvailability instance
HmsApiAvailability client = new HmsApiAvailability();

// 0: HMS Core (APK) is available.
// 1: No HMS Core (APK) is found on device.
// 2: HMS Core (APK) installed is out of date.
// 3: HMS Core (APK) installed on the device is unavailable.
// 9: HMS Core (APK) installed on the device is not the official version.
// 21: The device is too old to support HMS Core (APK).
int status = await client.isHMSAvailable();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** device_info plugin is now deprecated.
Use https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus , which provided the similar functionality.

---

You can fetch device manufacture to detect Huawie device

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.manufacturer}');
```

plugin used - https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

**Or**
You can check the availability of `GooglePlayServices` in the device

```
GooglePlayServicesAvailability availability = await GoogleApiAvailability.instance.checkGooglePlayServicesAvailability();
```

Plugin required - https://pub.dev/packages/google_api_availability

**Note:** If using `GooglePlayServices` check, need to add platform check also as it returns false in case of iOS devices.

Comment: For future readers. **DON'T USE THE FIRST PART OF THIS THIS SOLUTION**
The Flutter plugin suggested (device_info) is no more maintained by the author.

Comment: @Alaindeseine , thanks for the update, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Alaindeseine, yap, but we have **device_info_plus** package witch maintained by community.

Answer (score 1):

The method for judging whether HMS is available in the device is as follows：

HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context)

​Implement check if HMS are available.

```
public class HmsGmsUtil {
    private static final String TAG = "HmsGmsUtil";

    /**
     * Whether the HMS service on the device is available.
     *
     * @param context android context
     * @return true:HMS service is available; false:HMS service is not available;
     */
    public static boolean isHmsAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (null != context) {
            int result = HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context);
            isAvailable = (com.huawei.hms.api.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == result);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "isHmsAvailable: " + isAvailable);
        return isAvailable;
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHmsSignBtn = findViewById(R.id.hms_sign_btn);
    mHmsSignBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signInByHms();
        }   

    mGmsSignBtn = findViewById(R.id.gms_sign_btn);
    mGmsSignBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signInByGms();
        }
    });

    boolean isHmsAvailable = HmsGmsUtil.isHmsAvailable(this);

    Log.i(TAG, "isHmsAvailable: " + isHmsAvailable + ", isGmsAvailable: " + isGmsAvailable);

    if (isHmsAvailable && !isGmsAvailable) {
        // Only hms, Sign In by huawei account.
        mHmsSignBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (!isHmsAvailable && isGmsAvailable) {
        // Only gms, Sign In by google account.
        mGmsSignBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (isHmsAvailable && isGmsAvailable) {
        // both hsm and hms, decide by developer.
        mGmsSignBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHmsSignBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (!isHmsAvailable && !isGmsAvailable) {
        // neither hms and gms, decide by developer.
        mHmsSignBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```